# not able to update/modify columns in query

Tags: ms-access-2007

before i have a question about "query for getting related image" and i got helpful answer http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/query-for-getting-related-image/ec5b7e35-1dda-4faf-89d9-ac7255697f4c

The SQL for this query is:

```
SELECT Table1.docno, Table1.title, Table1.progress, Table2.icon
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE IIf([progress]>=0.5,1,2)=[id])
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
 SELECT Table1.docno, Table1.title, Table1.progress, Table2.icon
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON IIf(Table1.progress>=0.5,1,2)=Table2.id
```

now i would like update or modify result data returned by query, for example i have added a [isselect] field (yes/no) in the underlying table (table1) and also put that in returned query, i need some times update [isselect] field , now it does not allow to me update any fields.

please help how i can have a query that returns like below question and also i can update data when it returns.

Comment: Try this site http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/edit-data-in-a-query-HA010097876.aspx

Comment: thanks this note at the site helped me, (Although you cannot edit the query datasheet in this case, you can edit the data in a form when the RecordsetType property of the form is set to Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates).